# How to use a formula (in string format) to calculate values

Tags: javascript, calculator, calc

How can I accept a formula from an input field to calculate a value?
For example `"(a+b)/100"`,  `"(a*b)/300"` `"(b/a)"`, etc.

The result should be the calculated value. So, given `A = 100; B = 200;` and  the formula is `"(a+b)"`, the result should be `300`.

Comment: You can use [`eval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `eval` which is actually not recommended. Create an object inside the function where the operator name is the key and symbol is the value like `+` or `*`. While calling the function pass an object with two values and the operator.

```js
function doCalculation({
  val1,
  val2,
  operation
}) {
  const obj = {
    add: '+',
    multiply: '*'
  }
  return parseInt(eval(`${val1}${obj[operation]}${val2}`), 10) / 100
}

console.log(doCalculation({
  val1: 100,
  val2: 200,
  operation: 'add'
}))
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using one of the existing libraries for parsing & evaluating equations.
There are quite a few of them available on [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/).

For example [`expr-eval`](https://github.com/silentmatt/expr-eval):

```js
const parser = new exprEval.Parser();
const expr = parser.parse("(a+b)/100");
console.log(expr.evaluate({ a: 100, b: 200 })); // 3
console.log(expr.evaluate({ a: 200, b: 200 })); // 4
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/expr-eval@1.2.2/dist/bundle.min.js"></script>
```

Not only is this more robust than an `eval`-based approach, but it also uses a more math-oriented syntax in comparison to javascript.